# Datetime syntax error with Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to use Python datetime objects in my queries to a Postgres database using Psycopg2, but I have the following error :

The code :

```
# createdat is a datetime variable I used before
print(type(createdat))

q = """
    select created_at
    from mytable t
    and t.created_at < %(createdat)s
    """ % {
        'createdat' : createdat
        }

read.execute(q)
```

Returns :

```
<type 'datetime.datetime'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 346, in <module>
    read.execute(q)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 120, in execute
    return super(DictCursor, self).execute(query, vars)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "20"
LINE 6:         and created_at < 2015-05-05 20:22:22
```

Any idea ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know where your `createdat` comes from but you shouldn't perform parameters injection yourself. [Let psycopg2 handle parameters itself](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). (Plus it will more likely solve your issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
q = """
select created_at
from mytable t
and t.created_at < %(createdat)s
"""

read.execute(q, {'createdat' : createdat})
```

Try this way, Psycopg2 will do everything by itself